# Como acessar um metodo em uma function javascript no angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-7

Estou utilizando um plugin em Jquery e ele funciona muito bem no Angular, porém eu quero chamar um método de serviço dentro de uma função de um alerta, segue abaixo o código:

evento click que cria a modal

```
<button class="button small alert" (click)="didTouchDeleteBrand(brand)"><span class="mif-bin"></span> Excluir</button>
```

método que exibe a modal e ao clicar em sim ele gera o erro

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'brandService' of undefined
```

codigo:

```
  constructor(private router: Router, private brandService: BrandService) {}

  public didTouchDeleteBrand(brand: Brand) {

function removeItem(teste){
  this.brandService.deleteBrand(teste.BrandID).subscribe(
    () => { 
      this.loadTableContent('');
    },
    (err) => { console.log(err); 
    }
  );
}
Metro4.dialog.create({
  title: "Confirmação de exclusão",
  content: "<div>Deseja realmente excluir este item?</div>",
  actions: [
      {
          caption: "Sim",
          cls: "js-dialog-close alert",
          onclick: function(){
            console.log(brand.BrandID);
            removeItem(brand.BrandID);
          }
      },
      {
          caption: "Cancelar",
          cls: "js-dialog-close"
      }
  ]
});
}
```

Comment: Por que vc declara um metodo dentro do outro? Declara ele no seu componente e chama usando o this.

Comment: No seu construtor, vc está importanto como privado "private brandService: BrandService", veja se ele está mapeado em cima, e se no caso ele não seria public.